# Are multiple last used paths in a FileDialog possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, directory, openfiledialog

I am developing a WPF application that needs to load and save images, videos, sounds and projects. Now I would like to have different "spaces" of last used directories, e.g.:

1. open project: initial path = some directory (unimportant right now)
2. open video file: initial path = default video folder
3. save project as: initial path = effectively used directory in step 1

Using the default behaviour of an OpenFileDialog I am either bound to restore the initial path for each dialogue or have a mixed last-used-directory "space" for all types of files alltogether.

What came to mind was that I could save the last used directory by hand, categorized by file type (using some textfile on the computer), and set the initial value of the next dialogue to the proper value read from this file. But is there a simpler way to accomplish the desired behaviour?

Comment: For 2 you could perhaps use,             Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos);

Comment: For 1 and 3 i guess you will have to persist things on your own. Like writing to registry or file (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the applications settings?

Open your project properties and enter in a string for Directory (or whatever you want), then you can access, modify and save it from your app with something like this:

```
var myDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.Directory;
```